# Read integers from file in MPI

Tags: mpi

I have a text file ("inputs.txt") that contain 5 integers(1 19 2 2000 7).
I try to read them while using MPI but without much success.
i can only read them as MPI_CHAR but not as MPI_INT.

```
MPI_File fh;
MPI_File_read(fh, &N, 1, MPI_INT, &status);
printf("%d \n", N);
MPI_File_close(&fh);
```

Any ideas?the file can be read from but only as MPI_CHAR,why?

Comment: Output:instead of showing 1 (first integer) it shows me 9515.. note:if i use MPI_CHAR it read it as 1 (but i want to read integers).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPI\_File\_read Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814905/mpi-file-read-error)

Comment: Ok i see,and if i want to read all the file as a char and than read from. How can i iterate from the start to the end of the file

Comment: you can use `sscanf()`. imho, *not* using MPI-IO would be much simpler here.